# Data integrity when referencing many-to-many relationship in sql

Tags: sql

Consider the following tables:

**db.quiz**

```
- ID: int 
- name: varchar(50)
```

**db.quiz_device**

```
- quiz_id: int (FK db.quiz.id)
- device_id: int (FK db.device.id)
```

**db.device**

```
- ID: int
- manufacturer: varchar(50)
- name: varchar(50)
- model: varchar(50)
```

**db.quiz_responses**

```
- ID: int 
- quiz_id: int (FK db.quiz.id)
- device_id: int (FK db.device.id)
- score: int
```

The above represents a quiz which is getting initialized with a collection of devices. From the quiz, a subject rates each device with a score between 1 and 10, and the results are stored in `quiz_responses`.

The above database design has a data integrity problem because `quiz_responses` may reference devices that are not within the scope of `quiz`.

To me, I have a hard time finding alternative ways of designing this, so that the devices which can be referenced in `quiz_responses` only entail the devices that belong to the `quiz_id` FK in `quiz_responses`.

In this case, would this be an acceptable issue, or could this be approached in another way?

Answer (score 0):

In the table db.quiz_device create a single PK column and make this the FK column in quiz_responses, rather than the 2 columns you have at the moment e.g.

db.quiz_device

- id: int (PK)
- quiz_id: int (FK db.quiz.id)
- device_id: int (FK db.device.id)

quiz_responses

- ID: int
- quiz_device_id: int (FK db.quiz_device.id)
- score: int

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NickW - Does that solve the issue? It is correct that I may only reference devices that has a relationship to a quiz, but it may be a relationship between any quiz and any device.